# MySql индексация datetime

Tags: mysql

`` WHERE `date_time` BETWEEN '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-02' `` - Подхватывает индекс

`` WHERE `date_time` BETWEEN '2018-01-01' and '2018-03-01' `` - Не подхватывает

Кто может объяснить в чем проблема? Таблица 13 лямов записей

Comment: Ну анализатор считает, что селективность недостаточна для использования индекса. Имеет право (и не факт, что он неправ). Сколько записей из этих 13кк соответствуют второму условию? В крайнем случае пересчитайте статистику.

Comment: 8 миллионов результат второго запроса

Comment: А тогда чего Вы хотите? использование индекса выгодно при селективности (в среднем) не более 5-7%... а у Вас более 60%. Анализатор прав.

Comment: Не знал про это спасибо.